# Can a JSON name-value pair have an empty name?

Tags: json

I am testing my JSON code with sample.json from the test suite [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-test-suite/) and it contains a lot of name-value pairs where the name is just an empty string, i.e. "". Is this correct? RFC4627 just states that the name SHOULD be unique but does not mention empty names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The specification](http://www.json.org) defines objects as such:

```
object
    {}
    { members }

members
    pair
    pair , members

pair
    string : value
    array

string
    ""
    " chars "
```

In other words, an object may be empty or contain `members`. `members` are `pair`s. A `pair` is a `string : value`. A `string` is `""` or `" chars "`.

That means empty strings are valid strings which are valid in a pair which is a valid member which is valid in objects.

Answer (score 2):

According to diagrams at http://www.json.org/ (which is probably as official as you can get), names are just strings, and strings can of course be empty.