# Sending empty array to webapi

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to POST an empty javascript array `[]` to webAPI and have it create an empty list of integers. I also want it so if I post javascript `null` to webAPI that it assigns null to the list of integers.

JS:

```
var intArray = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/ListOfInts',
    data: {'' : intArray},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

c# webapi

```
[HttpPost]
public void ListOfInts([FromBody]List<int> input)
```

Problem 1) Jquery refuses to send data `{'' : []}` as the post payload. As soon as I add something in the array it works such as `{'' : [1,2,3]}`

Problem 2)  [Passing empty js array to controller gives null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108272/passing-empty-js-array-to-controller-gives-null) Based on what i read even if I do get it to post an empty array, it will initialize the list as null.  Discussed solutions have it so that the list is always initializes as empty but I don't want that. I want it to be null in some case (when null/undefined is sent to it) and when `[]` is sent it should initialize as empty.

Edit: See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1 about why I am using `{'' : []}`

Comment: Have you tried to send just data: intArray ?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work at all. WebAPI doesnt know how to handle it

Comment: In WebApi, differentiating between null and empty in a request can be difficult.  If you are using those to somehow set some sort of "state" in your application, I would rethink how you are doing it.  Possibly sending some sort of flag or something that will properly initialize your list on the server.

Answer (score 25):

Use `JSON.stringify(intArray)` and `contentType: 'application/json'` works for me:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/values",
     method: "POST",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify([])
});
```

[image]

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/values",
     method: "POST",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: null
});
```

[image]

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/api/values",
      method: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3])
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
data: {'' : intArray},
```

a blank key name is not allowed in JSON.

Just send the array itself.

```
data: intArray,
```

Comment: This is required by webAPI when sending a valuetype

Comment: According to [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33254385/548304), empty keys are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use JSON.stringify() to convert javascript object to JSON string.

**2.** Use contentType: 'application/json' as it is correct MIME media type for JSON.  [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/1074179)

**3** dataType is not necessary

**data**: JSON.stringify(intArray),
**contentType**: 'application/json'